# I cannot get the clipping to go away when I use hover

Tags: css

For some reason my code will not allow me to disable clipping when i hover over an object. Here is the code that I am using.
I am pretty sure I have everything right and I am using Google Chrome if that helps.

```
<section id="map">
     <figure id="point0">
        <img src="image0.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>3:30 a.m.</time> Start from the Longs Peak Ranger
           Station, nine miles south of Estes Park. Be sure to pack 
           food, extra water, 
           sunblock, warm clothes, gloves, and caps.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point1">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>5:30 a.m.</time> Stop at Mills Moraine for a 
           view of the sunrise.
       </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point2">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>7:30 a.m.</time> Time for a break at Granite Pass.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point3">
        <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>8:30 a.m.</time> Climb through the Boulder Field 
           on the way to the Keyhole.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point4">
        <img src="image4.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>9:00 a.m.</time> Stop at the
           Agnes Vaille shelter for a well-deserved breakfast.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point5">
        <img src="image5.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>9:30 a.m.</time> It's time to go through
           the Keyhole. Be prepared for heavy winds.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point6">
        <img src="image6.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>10:00 a.m.</time> Follow the painted targets 
           along the Ledges.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point7">
        <img src="image7.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>11:00 a.m.</time> Take special care when crossing 
           the Narrows.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point8">
        <img src="image8.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>11:15 a.m.</time> You're almost there! Climb the
           Homestretch to reach the summit.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure id="point9">
        <img src="image9.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>
           <time>11:45 a.m.</time> Congratulations, you've reached 
           the top! Time for lunch and a few photos.
        </figcaption>
     </figure>

  </section>





figure {
    background-color: rgb(70, 76, 222);
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    clip: rect(auto, 20px, 20px, auto);
}

figure:hover {
    clip: none;
    z-index: 2;

}

figure figcaption {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

so the hover will not disable the clip effect and let the image become unclipped and it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
figure:hover {
    clip: none;
    z-index: 2;

}
```

The default should be clip: auto I believe:

```
figure:hover {
    clip: auto;
    z-index: 2;

}
```

Comment: Happy to help! You may want to mark the answer accepted too, to help others who arrive here with the same issue :)